# Self modelling video technique

Tags: c#, .net, windows, video, video-processing

I am working on windows app where I have to replace face in any video with the picture taken by camera. How should I super impose any face in video.

Comment: There's a good chance yes.  You can do it!

Comment: Any tool or library available? I know adobe after effect is there but that don't serve my need. It needs me to create one more video with green screen background but I just want to replace face in existing video.

Comment: _[Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)_